# Shrinking JavaFX Graphics

Tags: java, javafx, copy, zooming, shrink

I'm looking for a way of rendering a scene hidden from view and then creating a second shrunken copy for initial display. Plainly I could render the contents a second time to create this copy only smaller. The original code written in another language though produced a better result using a smooth (spatially filtered) shrinking function to create the small copy. Is there such a bitmap copy/shrink/smooth function in JavaFX and is it any good?

Comment: There is a `setScaleX(double value)` function in `Node` class, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think, and I hope I have not misunderstood, that the setScale functions would be useful as part of "the other way" of doing it. In other words if I were to redraw the scene rather than execute a bitmap copy.

Comment: Not entirely sure I understand the question, but you can [`snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) the existing scene to create an `Image` and then display the image scaled in an [`ImageView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html). Use `setFitHeight()`, `setFitWidth()`, `setPreserveRatio()` and `setSmooth()` to control the scaling. This will only give a static view of the scene, so if, e.g., there are animations you won't see those in the image.

Comment: Sounds like that could be the method. It only needs be static. If I understand then the setFitHeight() will allow me to shrink the captured image along with the corresponding setFit Width() such that making these to say half the original would squeeze the scene into one quarter the number of displayed pixels, for example. It seems then that setSmooth() being true will give a spatially filtered down-sized version. Only question now is how well does the filtering work? Thanks a lot by-the-way James.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a snapshot of a scene as a `WritableImage` as follows:

```
Scene scene =  ... ;

Image image = scene.snapshot(null);
```

and then display a scaled version of it in an image view with:

```
ImageView sceneImage = new ImageView();
sceneImage.setFitWidth(desiredWidth);
sceneImage.setFitHeight(desiredHeight);
// force aspect ratio to be preserved if fitWidth and fitHeight would distort it:
sceneImage.setPreserveRatio(true);
// this provides a tiny bit of control over the scaling used:
sceneImage.setSmooth(true);

sceneImage.setImage(image);
```